# The Select Dropdown doesn't update back after reload

Tags: reactjs, json, drop-down-menu, onchange

I created a form where the user inputs data and when the button Save is clicked the data are saved to a database. Everything works fine. You can notice that the country is selected from a memo list and I used a function to save the data rather than a lambda function like the name and the address because I couldn't figure it out. My problem is when I reload the page the country doesn't get back to the form like the name and the address but is stored in the database. The issue is in the code below.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect , useMemo} from 'react';
import { Button, Row, Col, Form, InputGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';
import obtainFromServer from '../Services/fetchService';
import { useLocalState } from '../util/useLocalStorage';
import countryList from 'react-select-country-list';
import Select from 'react-select';

const TrademarkView = () => {
    const [jwt, setJwt] = useLocalState("", "jwt"); //Remove setJwt if we don't use it at the end
    const trademarkId = window.location.href.split("/trademarks/")[1];
    const [trademark, setTrademark] = useState({
        address: "",
        country: "",
        name: "",
    });


    //Countries
    const [countryinit, setCountryinit] = useState({
        value: "",
        label: "",
    });
    const options = useMemo(() => countryList().getData(), []);

    const changeHandler = countryinit => {
        setCountryinit(countryinit);
        console.log(countryinit);
        updateTrademark("country",countryinit.label)        
      }
    const styleCountries = {
        display: "inline-block",
        width: "300px"
      };


    function updateTrademark(prop, value){
        const newTrademark = {...trademark}
        newTrademark[prop] = value;
        setTrademark(newTrademark);
    }

    function saveTrademark(){
        obtainFromServer(`/api/trademarks/${trademarkId}`, "PUT", jwt, trademark).then(
            (trademarkData) =>{
                setTrademark(trademarkData);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        obtainFromServer(`/api/trademarks/${trademarkId}`, "GET", jwt)
        .then(trademarkData => {
            if(trademarkData.address === null) trademarkData.address = "";
            if(trademarkData.name === null) trademarkData.name = "";
            setTrademark(trademarkData);
        });
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            {trademark ? (
                <>

            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Form className='m-5'>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formGridName" className="mb-2">
                            <Form.Label>Name:</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control value={trademark.name} onChange={(e) => updateTrademark("name",e.target.value)}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress">
                            <Form.Label>Address:</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="textarea" placeholder="1234 Main St" rows={3} value={trademark.address} onChange={(e) => updateTrademark("address",e.target.value)}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridCountry">
                            <Form.Label>Country:</Form.Label>
                            <div style={styleCountries}><Select options={options} value={countryinit} onChange={changeHandler} /></div>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
                </Col>
                <Row className='mx-1 px-5'>
                    <Button onClick={() => saveTrademark()}>Save</Button>                    
                </Row>
                
            </Row>
            </>
            ) : (
                <></>
            )}
           
        </div>
    );
};

export default TrademarkView;
```

The countryinit has a value(it's the initials of the country) and a label(it's the name of the country). You can see that when I am updating the database I am only sending the label. I have a console.log so you can see the country object.

How can I get the country to be selected after a reload?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: The problem is because the countryinit is an object and I am only sending the label  to the database.

Comment: The problem is that you never read this value after reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Changed the select to this and it worked.

```
<Select options={options} value={options.filter((option) => option.value === trademark.country)} onChange={(e) => updateTrademark("country",e.value)} />
```

Basically the problem as I mention before is that the country it was an object. And I couldn't send the whole object to the database and I was sending the label which it was wrong. Now I am sending the value to the database and when reading I am redirecting the value from the database to the selected value and setting the label.